# When do I decide a logistic model with no roots equals 0?

Tags: exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

I have a logistic model function:

$$ y=\frac{424.92}{1+0.37027e^{0.000715x}}$$

This exponential model has an asymptote at $y=0$, and hence doesn't ever meet the $x$-axis. However, I need to discern when the quantity being measured ceases to exist (i.e. when it reaches zero). Is there some way I can calculate this anyway? Is there some cut-off point where I decide that the $y$-value becomes negligible?

Comment: You are supposed to have a negative exponent in the denominator for a logistic model, unless you are considering $x<0$, right?

Comment: @JoshuaWang It normally is negative, however I'm modelling the decay of something so the negative cancels out, making the exponent positive. I think. Unless I made some mistake somewhere

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a handy tutorial and formatting guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Well, this is a *model*. Thus, it's an approximation to a real world problem. The model never hits zero but the real world value can. It's really up to you to decide what numeric value produced by the model should be considered as effectively zero. That depends on considerations outside the model, such as the application, units, etc.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Alright, I'll consider this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity is never $0$, but you can find the value of $x$ after which it becomes arbitrarily small. Say we want to know when we have $y<\varepsilon$ for some small positive number $\varepsilon$. Then we have $$\frac{424.92}{1+0.37027 e^{0.000715x}}<\varepsilon.$$ Taking reciprocals: $$\frac{1+0.37027 e^{0.000715x}}{424.92}>\varepsilon$$ and solving for $x$:$$\frac{424.92\varepsilon-1}{0.37027}<e^{0.000715x}$$ $$\log{\left(\frac{424.92\varepsilon-1}{0.37027}\right)}/0.000715<x.$$ So for any $x$ larger than this quantity, you will have $y<\varepsilon$.
So, you can decide what value of $\varepsilon$ can be considered as "negligible" in your model and then find what value of $x$ makes your $y$ this small.

Comment: I see, okay, thank you. So if I was to say that any number below y=1 would be considered negligible, then the value of x would be about 9850?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.